# Using wp_insert_post for one custom type inside another custom post types's save function - big problem

Tags: custom-post-types

**Hi, I am running into a problem that is somehow related to me inserting a custom post of some type, while the save function of another custom post type is underway.**

In post type `course` I added a meta box so I can add a post type `group` that is associated with post type `course`.

Upon the `course` saving process, meta data is added for this `group` type, when no such meta data should be added.

So in the `course` save function I have:

```php
add_action( 'save_post_sfwd-courses', 'ld_save_additional_course_settings');
function ld_save_additional_course_settings($post_id)

    if (!isset($_POST['ld_nonce_additional_course_settings'])) return;

    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['ld_nonce_additional_course_settings'], 'ld_meta_box_additional_course_settings')) {
        return;
    }

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return;

    // deal with groups - need to delete any previous groups that are no longer here
    global $wpdb;
    $prev_grps= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT object_id FROM wp_ld_content_relations WHERE related_course = '$post_id' AND object_type='sfwg-groups'", ARRAY_N);

    // loop through listed groups - if object_id is set that means we only need to update
    $cur_grps=[];
    if (isset($_POST['groups']) && !empty($_POST['groups'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['groups'] as $group) {
            $grp_id=null;
            if (!empty($group['object_id'])) {
                $grp_id = $group['object_id'];
            }
            $groupname='';
            if (isset($group['post_title']) && !empty($group['post_title'])) $groupname = $group['post_title'];
            $startdate ='';
            if (isset($group['startdate'])  && !empty($group['startdate']))  $startdate = $group['startdate'];
            if (!empty($groupname)) {


               $post_status = 'publish';

               $args = [
               'post_title' => $groupname,
               'post_type' => 'groups',
               'comment_status' => 'closed',
               'ping_status' => 'closed',
               'post_status' => $post_status
                ];

               if (!is_null($grp_id)) {
                   $args['ID'] = $grp_id;
                   $grp_id = wp_update_post($args);
               } else {
                   $grp_id = wp_insert_post($args);
               }
               if (grp_id) $cur_grps[] = $result;
            }

        }
    }
    // delete any groups no longer attached to course
    if (!empty($prev_grps) ) {
        $diff = array_diff($prev_grps, $cur_grps);
        if (!empty($diff)) {
            foreach ($diff as $dif) {
                wp_delete_post($dif); // this will trigger delete hook and there needs to then be cleanup actions
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For instance, in the `course` admin editor I can add some group.

After `wp_insert_post` is called, a hook (which I have no control over) for this `course` post type is fired, which is

```php
function save_post_data( $post_id = 0, $saved_post = null, $update = null ) {

...
bunch of stuff here, course settings checked, then an update_post_meta called

but post_id here is the group id that was just inserted...
```

And that hook is set by

```
add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_post_data'), 10, 3 );
```

So this hook thinks it is dealing with `course`, but it is dealing with `group`...

After it is triggered from the `group` insert it is called again, where the post_id is indeed the `course` id.

So just not sure what I need to do to remedy this behavior... Maybe `remove_action` before `wp_insert_post` then reset the action after? I see various examples where syntax is

```
remove_action('hook', array($this, 'hook_function'))
```

But in my script, I don't have access to the `course` class's $this variable, so not sure how I am supposed to deactivate the `course` class's hook.

Ideas?

Thank!!!!

thanks,
Brian

Edit: added more detail - see above

Comment: you can't insert post inside an insert post without checks or you'll trigger infinite loops, can you edit your question to include your code?

Comment: Just added some more info and ran through debugger and found exact place where problem is happening. Added some info above. Now question is, what is correct way to do what I am trying to do? :-)

Comment: can you edit it again but this time include the code? You've censored parts of it, I suspect to make it more concise or keep only the bits you consider relevant, but you've removed vital information. To save us going back and forth re-adding in parts, can you just include the entire function without any *helpful* edits?

Comment: Also the code you added implies this is possibly a learndash site, and you're working with Learn Dash APIs, this is also super important context that was concealed. Can you provide a full context, what you're trying to do that lead to this ( don't describe what you're trying to do in code, but what the problem you're trying to solve is that lead to this solution you're having issues with )

Comment: Ok, it is work in progress, but I added the code for the course save hook. Maybe I just need to do a remove_action? I tried doing $that = new SFWD_CPT_Instance('sfwd-courses' );remove_action('save_post', array( $that, 'save_post_data')); before the wp_insert but it creates a different instance than the type I need, because the constructor expects an array, and I wasn't sure how to build the needed array. The idea here is to allow me to add course groups from the course page without having to use the Groups admin page...

Comment: I made some progress: I see that there is global var of learndash post types./ If I set remove_action('save_post', array( $sfwd_lms->post_types['sfwd-courses'], 'save_post_data')); the meta data for the group is no longer added. That is good. But I noticed other meta data associated with other plugins being added for the created group. So the question becomes: how to do this insert_post and totally disable save_post hooks for all plugins, then set back to how they were after the insert_post?

Comment: On 2nd thought - I don't want to disable hooks because other plugins might depend on groups being saved. So really I need to make wordpress think the group is the current post type being edited at this point.